# Correct way to write degree north

Tags: siunitx, units

When referring to different locations on the globe in longitude-latitude coordinates, what is the correct way to write, e.g., 10 degree north? Note that in this case I have to distinguish between degree north and degree south (so 10 degree south may NOT be written as -10 degree north; therefore an indication of north/south is required each time)

[The BIPM](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3-3.html) gives gives a hint on how to handle degree Celsius. But I did not find anything with regard to geographic coordinates.

The options I can think of right now:

```
10\si{\degree} N
10\si{\degree}\,N
10\si{\degree}N
10\,\si{\degree} N
10\,\si{\degree}\,N
10\,\si{\degree}N
```

Comment: `siunitx` package has a command `\ang` to typeset angles / geographical coordinates. Try `\ang{10}N`

Comment: Did not know that, thanks @Troy! So in terms of spacing that would then be the same as `10\si{\degree}N` (or `10$^\circ$N`), right? (I'm just asking because I can't actually use the `siunitx` package - just didn't want to make the question more complicated than it needs to be)

Comment: Yup, certainly seems like it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To typeset angles / geographical coordinates, you can use this command from the `siunitx` package:

```
\ang{<angle>}
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \ang{10}N (With \texttt{siunitx})

    10$^\circ$N (Without \texttt{siunitx})
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The output without using `siunitx` package is also shown (motivated from the comments).